# Как сделать одну выборку для каждого пользователя

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

У меня в таблице примерно такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это таблица отправки сообщений. В этой таблице могут находиться больше 10000 записей. У меня например id = 1  Я бы хотел узнать, как получить последнюю запись с тем пользователем, которым я переписывался? Например с одним пользователем(3) есть записи id = 1, 4, 7. Чтобы получить последнюю запись (в данном случае id = 7) и так с каждым, одним запросом.

Comment: where from = 1 and to = 3 order by id desc limit 1 ?

Comment: Дело в том, что это пример. Мне не известно с какими пользователями именно переписывался

Answer (score 1):

Все таки это задача на использование групповых функций. Вот запрос который выдаст для каждого пользователя последнее сообщение для конкретного отправителя:

```
select
  max(t.id) max_id
from messges_tables t
where t.to_user_id = 1
group by t.from_user_id
```

---

Групповые функции работают на наборах строк с одинаковыми значениями (определяется в `group by`), чтобы выдать один результат на группу. К групповым функций относятся `AVG`, `MIN`, `MAX` и т.д.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый

Answer (score 0):

Как то так. Запрос вернет по одной строке для пользователя 1 ('from') и последней записью каждого собеседника

```
WITH q AS
         (
         SELECT  c.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `to` ORDER BY id DESC) rn
         FROM messages c
         WHERE c.`from` = 1

         )
SELECT   *
FROM     q
WHERE    rn = 1
```

Comment: Извините, может показаться вопрос странным, но я впервые вижу WITH AS. Что оно вообще делает?)

Comment: Не нашел русскую документацию. [Вот оригинал](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html)

Если кратко - то это временная таблица создается, с которой можно работать как с обычной .

Comment: А она как то влияет на производительность или нагрузку?

Comment: Если есть индексы, то даже многомиллионная таблица не вызовет проблем. Вопрос оптимизации - это уже отдельная тема